# Remove line under Windows 10 taskbar icons

Tags: windows-10, taskbar, icons, themes

That "underline" underneath taskbar icons was apparently [added to indicate the application is open](https://www.quora.com/Are-Windows-10-taskbar-items-suppose-to-have-a-green-underline-How-can-I-remove-it) (vs. just pinned). I don't need this indicator.

**Is there any way to remove the open application indicator that appears as a line underneath Windows 10 taskbar items?**

I tried this [custom theme](http://www.tenforums.com/general-support/9816-how-get-rid-line-under-taskbar-icons-5.html#post415729), but it did not work. Other places where this has been asked:

- [7+ Taskbar Tweaker comments](http://rammichael.com/7-taskbar-tweaker-and-windows-10#comment-5455)
- [How do I remove the underline under programs with only 1 window open?](https://www.reddit.com/r/Windows10/comments/3kmxml/how_do_i_remove_the_underline_under_programs_with/)
- [Getting rid of the underline on active apps?](https://www.reddit.com/r/Windows10/comments/3f9z5t/getting_rid_of_the_underline_on_active_apps/)

Answer (score 1):

**update:** This solution had some weird side-effects, so I stopped using it. Leaving for historical purposes (and people who don't want to shell out a few bucks for the new solution I use.)

[image]

**I figured it out: NoLine custom theme + UltraUXThemePatcher!**

Upvote/comment if you'd like the files required with detailed instructions. (You can mess up your computer if you don't install the correct theme that matches your version of Windows.)

Answer (score -1):

My first solution had some weird side effects so I ended up not using it.

I found a better solution called [StartIsBack++](https://startisback.com/).